# Mockito vs Test Implementation of class

Tags: android, junit, mocking, mockito

I have been going through source code of `Volley` and have found that for every class or interface there is a test implementation.

Is it preferable to write `Test` class for every other class than using `Mockito` to just mock objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A broad question but let's collect the underlying facts:

- writing your own custom test "stubs" enables you to implement your "own" vision of "test support"
- especially, you do not have any dependencies to a mocking framework

In other words: you decide to re-invent the wheel to a certain degree. That prevents you running into bugs other people put down, at the risk of making your own mistakes.

In that sense, this boils down to the old discussion "buy or make yourself".

When talking about test cases, there are various experts that suggest to not rely on mocking frameworks. So this is a common practice, but I think a "minority" one.

My personal two cents here: ideally, you should write production code that can be tested without any mocking framework. But that isn't always possible. And for those cases, you have *one* mocking framework in your toolbox. You know how to use that in a reasonable way to get your testing done. I would find it way too cumbersome to do all test stubs manually. A lot of effort for a relatively small gain.